# How to divide all columns of a numeric table by the last column in SQL Server except ID column and the last column as divisor?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In SQL Server I am going to divide all columns of a table by the last column in that ID column and the last column itself are not included.
Suppose the data is numeric.
The simple way is to use the following code consider with 4 columns and one ID column:

```
update Table1
set col1 = col1/col4, col2 = col2/col4, col2 = col2/col4
where id = ...
```

and this must be repeated for updating other records too.
The problem is that we have no idea how many columns are there. So, it seems we need some variables and and loops to detect columns and update them for each record.

[image]

and after updating

[image]

I need a code to do it for any table with numeric values.

Comment: Are you really using unsupported software?  How can you not know what columns are in a table?

Comment: *The problem is that we have no idea how many columns are there*: if you have a table, then you should know the columns it has. You might want to use more context about the problem you are trying to solve here.

Comment: In some huge software systems whose subsystems have their own businesses and it might not be predictable what columns there will be

Comment: Please don't duplicate your questions.

Comment: The website closed the question before it get answered and that's why I had to post it again. @Larnu

Comment: Then you need to edit the original question to make it on topic and it'l be reopened, @AzimRe . Though you have an answer in your other question anyway; just use the divide operator (`/`).

Comment: Here is some dynamic sql  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=4c9a63433eb1fd3472036e0d30f5cc95  You'll just need to change YOURTABLE or make it into a variable